# Function call and context save to stack

Tags: function, stack, rtos

I am very interested in real time operating systems for micro-controllers, so I am doing a deep research on the topic. At the high level I understand all the general mechanisms of an OS.

In order to better learn it I decided to write a very simple kernel that does nothing but the context switch. This raised a lot of additional - practical questions to me. I was able to cope with many of them but I am still in doubt with the main thing - Saving context (all the CPU registers, and stack pointer) of a current task and restore context of a new task.

In general, OS use some function (lets say *OSContextSwitch())* that preserves all the actions for the context switch. The body of the *OSContextSwitch()* is mainly written in assembly (inline assembly in C body function). But when the *OSContextSwitch()* is called by the scheduler, as far as I know, on a function call some of the CPU registers are preserved on the stack by the compiler (actually by the code generated by the compiler).

Finally, the question is: How to know which of the CPU registers are already preserved by the compiler to the stack so I can preserve the rest ? If I preserved all the registers regardless of the compiler behaviour, obviously there will be some stack leakage.

Comment: It's not obvious to me.  If you're writing code to push stuff on the stack aren't you also writing code to pop that stuff off the stack?  So as long as you pop everything that you pushed then you should be OK.  Why would it matter if you push/pop unnecessary stuff?  (Or, what do you mean by "stack leakage"?)

Answer (score 1):

Such function should be written either as pure assembly (so *NOT* an assembly block inside a C function) or as a "naked" C function with nothing more than assembly block. Doing anything in between is a straight road to messing things up.

As for the registers which you should save - generally you need to know the ABI for your platform, which says that some registers are saved by caller and some should be saved by callee - you generally need to save/restore only the ones which are normally saved by callee. If you save all of them nothing wrong will happen - your code will only be slightly slower and use a little more RAM, but this will be a good place to start.

Here's a typical context switch implementation for ARM Cortex-M microcontrollers - https://github.com/DISTORTEC/distortos/blob/master/source/architecture/ARM/ARMv6-M-ARMv7-M/ARMv6-M-ARMv7-M-PendSV_Handler.cpp#L76